# Makefile linux fortran code

Tags: linux, make

How should I fix this Error while running my makefile?

> *****No rule to make target `sh2st2.f95`, needed by `sh2st2.o`.  Stop.*****

My makefile is as follows:

```
Makefile: sh2st2.o sh3dt0.o sh4dt2.o Makefile.o
        f95 -o Makefile sh2st2.o sh3dt0.o sh4dt2.o Makefile.o
Makefile.o: Makefile.f95
        f95 -o-c Makefile.f95
sh2st2.o: sh2st2.f95
        f95 -o-c sh2st2.f95
sh3dt0.o:  sh3dt0.f95
        f95 -o-c sh3dt0.f95
sh4dt2.o:  sh4dt2.f95
        f95 -o-c sh4dt2.f95
```

Comment: Make can not find the source file `sh2st2.f95`, so it thinks it needs to make it.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want you executable to be called `Makefile`. You probably want just `-c` rather than `-o -c`, You need a source file called `sh2st2.f95`, and after you have provided that you will need `sh3dt0.f95`, `sh4dt2.f95` and `Makefile.f95`.